# Delete commit in git

Tags: git

I want to remove a commit from my repository, but using reset, reset --hard, and reset --soft removes all commits after the commit I specified and i want to keep those commits.

This is an example commit list: [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnsEZ.png)

And i want this result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c8x5.png)

But i get this: [fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GlaT.png)

How can i get the result i want? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A commit represents the **difference between** two different versions of the code. It is not possible to just "remove" one, because then the commits *after* that point don't properly apply. There are **at least two completely different** use cases: making the next commit apply both its own change, plus the "removed" change, merged together; or making it so that the changes from the "removed" commit *never occur*. The question cannot be answered without a precise understanding of what should happen.

Comment: That said: [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [look for an existing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+commit+is%3Aquestion) question that matches your requirements. Also, make sure you understand that `git` is the program; `github` is a **web site** that tries to offer friendlier access to some of the things that `git` can do (and also hosts your upstream repository). You will almost certainly have more luck with a task like this by using the command-line `git` locally.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not actually. A commit is actually a directory tree, not the diff.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "A commit represents the difference" No it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
git push origin -f
```

I've used it before and it's work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your answers, I'll tell you what I used: there is a utility called rebase that allows us to make changes in our commit tree, the option squeeze merge several commits into one, the only drawback is that all the next commits are rewritten and their creation date is changed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).